# Getting same value of a member variable in java

Tags: java

I wrote a test program in java in which the object has 3 parameters:

```
id, name and age.
```

The name and age are initialised using constructor but id should be incremented automatically from the last id. (and it should start from 1 for 1st created object).

I used `id` as **static variable** to achieve the same.

```
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    private static int id = 1;
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Test(String name, int age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        id++;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return id + " " + name + "," + age;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        Test c1 = new Test("A", 12);
        Test c2 = new Test("B", 32);
        Test c3 = new Test("C", 58);
        Test c4 = new Test("D", 17);
        Test c5 = new Test("E", 42);

        ArrayList<Test> testList =  new ArrayList<Test>();

        testList.add(c1);
        testList.add(c2);
        testList.add(c3);
        testList.add(c4);
        testList.add(c5);

        for(int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(testList.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

But in the output I am getting same id for all the test objects.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your class will need *two* id type fields, one private to the instance, and another, say called lastId, that is static.

Comment: You need to use Factory pattern to create objects to achieve this goal

Comment: `id` is static. Get a book about Java

Comment: You define id as static and then wonder why each instance has the same id? You might want to read an introductory text on Java to see what static means and what effects it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static variable means that the variable is shared between all the instances of the given class, if you change the value of a static variable in one of the instances it will be changed in all.

What you want to accomplish probably is doable in the next way:

```
class Test
{
    public static int counter = 1;
    private int id;
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Test(String name, int age)
    {
        this.id = counter;
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        counter++;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return id + " " + name + "," + age;
    }
....
```

Make the counter public, you might actually need to reference it from outside the class instance, or if you cannot afford to expose it as public make it private and create a static getter for it which will allow you to get the current id counter from outside the class.

Another option is to use the [Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) but probably that is not needed for this particular case.